# How to get results for distinct values using sql in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I am using the following query:

```
select MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID as Id
     , description
     , created_date 
from monitor_alert_instance 
where description in(
                    select distinct(description)  
                    from monitor_alert_instance
                    where co_mod_asset_id=1223
                    group by description
                    )
```

and the output result is:

[image]

How can I get the results based on latest (date and time) that will show three distinct values in the result set. The expected output is:

```
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--
| 766  |  Test.....                          |  14-03-04 14:56:51.000000000  |
| 765  |  Water_pH_sensor_malfunction        |  14-03-04 13:55:04.000000000  |
| 762  |  Water_turbidity_meter_malfunction  |  14-03-04 13:54:33.000000000  |
+----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--
```

Thanks

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. There is no difference between `distinct (description)` and `distinct description`. Or to put the it the other way: it's the same difference as between `select description` and `select (description)`. And `distinct` doesn't make sense for a sub-query used for the `IN` operator anyway. And finally: `group by` **and** `distinct` on the same column does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results you seem to want using aggregation:

```
select max(MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID) as Id, description, max(created_date) as created_date
from monitor_alert_instance 
where description in (select description 
                      from monitor_alert_instance
                      where co_mod_asset_id = 1223
                     )
group by description;
```

Note that I simplified the subquery.  The `distinct` is redundant when using `group by`.  And neither is necessarily when using `in`.

EDIT:

I think you can get the same result with this query:

```
select max(MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID) as Id, description, max(created_date) as created_date
from monitor_alert_instance 
group by description
having max(case when co_mod_asset_id = 1223 then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

The `having` clause makes sure that the description is for asset `1223`.

Which performs better depends on a number of factors, but this might perform better than the `in` version.  (Or the table may be small enough that any difference in performance is negligible.)

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions are working like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       description,
       created_date
from (
  select MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID as Id, 
         description
         created_date, 
         row_number() over (partition by description order by created_date desc) as rn
  from monitor_alert_instance 
  where co_mod_asset_id = 1223
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: where should I pass co_mod_asset_id=1223?

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I do that. A bit confused now.

Comment: @Novis: just add the where clause to the inner query (see my edit)